# UK Visa in an expired Nigerian passport - what to use?

Tags: visas, uk, passports

I am in Nigeria, my passport will expire in 4 months and I have a document to apply for a UK visiting Visa with that passport number.

Should I use it like that or go for another passport. If I choose to get another passport, how will I use it because of the passport number on the about to expired one in the document I want to use for Visa.

Comment: Have assumed you are a Nigerian citizen and updated the title accordingly, hope that's ok.

Comment: You haven't got the visa yet but only applied for it, is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traveling to the US with new passport, visa on the old one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36589/traveling-to-the-us-with-new-passport-visa-on-the-old-one)

Comment: The UK prefers that [visas be in an unexpired passport](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa) and, for some national, that the passport be valid for 6 months beyond the planned departure. With the timing of what you plan, It may be better (and easier) to renew your passport before applying for a UK visit visa.

Answer (score 4):

There are [two things you can definitely do](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa):

- Travel with your visa in the old passport and a new passport at the same time.
- Pay a fee to transfer the visa from one passport to the other.

So if you do get a UK visa in your current passport, you will in any case be able to travel with that visa and another passport after the first one expires.

I don't know exactly what will happen to the current visa application (e.g. whether you could put the visa in a new passport even though you submitted your old passport's number) but I would keep the old passport in any case.