# Can I get a UAE visa in a passport that expires 4 months after intended travel

Tags: dubai

I am flying into Dubai on the 5th of August and leaving on the 8th of August. Will I be able to get a visa for Dubai even though my passport expires on the 31st of January 2015? I am a South African citizen.

I will also be traveling to the UK and have received my visa for entry. I am not sure if I apply for a new passport this will mean I will have to get a new visa for the UK in the new passport as well.

Comment: Your question currently has two completely unrelated questions, I suggest revising the question to ask only one at a time and post another question for the second questions.

Comment: If you do decide to get a new passport, you can always use the old passport with the visa in it together with the new passport to enter the UK, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30767/uk-visa-in-an-expired-nigerian-passport-what-to-use

Answer (score 3):

Per [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=ZA&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=AE&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), as a South African citizen you require a visa in advance for the United Arab Emirates, and

> Passport or passport replacing documents of visitors must be   valid
>   for:
>
> - at least 3 months from the date of entry, for visits of up   to 3 months; or
> - at least 6 months from the date of entry, for visits
>     exceeding 3 months.

So you should be fine with your current passport.  Of course, since you need to apply for a visa at the embassy, they will tell you whether your passport is sufficient.